# Using Waitable Timer objects in VBA - invalid handle error

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, timer

I'm trying to use Waitable Timer objects in VBA, as I want to call something asynchronously with a delay of under 1 second (so no `Application.OnTime`) and *with arguments* (so no `SetTimer` API)

I haven't found someone attempting this anywhere else so I'm having to do it all from scratch, but I think it should be feasible. Here are the API declarations:

```
Public Declare Function CreateWaitableTimer Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateWaitableTimerA" ( _
                        ByVal lpTimerAttributes As Long, _
                        ByVal manualReset As Boolean, _
                        ByVal lpTimerName As Long) As Long
'The A meaning Ansi not Unicode https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/145/Q145727/

Public Declare Function SetWaitableTimer Lib "kernel32" ( _
                        timerHandle As Long, _
                        lpDueTime As fileTime, _
                        lPeriod As Long, _
                        pfnCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        lpArgToCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        fResume As Boolean) As Boolean
```

Which references a fileTime (struct)

```
'see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a28a32c6-df4e-41b9-94ce-6260812dd92f/problem-trying-to-run-32-bit-vba-program-on-a-64-bit-machine?forum=exceldev
Public Type fileTime
    dwLowDateTime As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type
```

**I am calling the API like this:**

```
'[...]

args = 1234 'public args As Long so it doesn't go out of scope while the timer is waiting

Dim timerHandle As Long
timerHandle = CreateWaitableTimer(0, False, 0)

Debug.Print GetSystemErrorMessageText(Err.LastDllError)

If Not SetWaitableTimer(timerHandle, absoluteDueTime, 0, AddressOf TimerCallbacks.pointerProc, VarPtr(args), False) Then
    Debug.Print "Error: "; GetSystemErrorMessageText(Err.LastDllError)
End If
```

[GetSystemErrorMessageText](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/formatmessage.aspx) comes from Chip Pearson. `absoluteDueTime` is a `fileTime` variable which is set to *Now + 1 second* earlier in the procedure.
I'm getting in the immediate window:

> 0 - The operation completed successfully.
>
> Error: 6 - The handle is invalid.

Meaning that `CreateWaitableTimer` appears to work but `SetWaitableTimer` does not.

FWIW `TimerCallbacks.pointerProc` looks like:

```
Public Sub pointerProc(ByVal argPtr As Long, ByVal timerLowValue As Long, ByVal timerHighValue As Long)
    Debug.Print "pointerProc called"; Time
End Sub
```

(but I don't think that's where the error is...)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem is with the implicit byRef of everything:

```
Public Declare Function SetWaitableTimer Lib "kernel32" ( _
                        timerHandle As Long, _
                        lpDueTime As fileTime, _
                        lPeriod As Long, _
                        pfnCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        lpArgToCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        fResume As Boolean) As Boolean
```

Pointers must be passed byVal or they are immediately deferenced? Is this correct:

```
Public Declare Function SetWaitableTimer Lib "kernel32" ( _
                        byVal timerHandle As Long, _
                        byRef lpDueTime As fileTime, _
                        byRef lPeriod As Long, _
                        byVal pfnCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        byVal lpArgToCompletionRoutine As Long, _
                        byRef fResume As Boolean) As Boolean
```

Not sure if all the `byRef`s are necessary